# Do asymptotic statistics "solve" the Behrens-Fisher problem?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, heteroscedasticity, asymptotics, two-sample

The Behrens-Fisher problem concerns comparing two means from independent (maybe multivariate) samples in a way robust to heteroskedasticity in the populations being compared. It seems that if one adopts an asymptotic approach, the problem is easy; so long as the statistician has two consistent estimators for the two population variances (and you make some appropriate assumptions), Slutzky's theorem combined with some Central Limit Theorem will yield the necessary asymptotics, and the means are asymptotically independent Normal random variables. Thus, the obvious statistic for comparing the means (the squared distance between the two relative to the sum of the sample covariance matrices, or sample variance in the univariate case) can be used. The test is not exact nor argued to be the most powerful, but it is an asymptotically consistent test if the null hypothesis of equality is false, with asymptotically correct Type I error if the null hypothesis is true.

I don't see asymptotic arguments mentioned in Behrens-Fisher problem discussions. Is it because of some framing of the problem that I'm missing, such as requiring that the result be most powerful or exact for finite samples or something?